# A reference for "every set containing an element $a$, allows a abelian group structure with identity element $a$"

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Do you know a reference which contains a proof for this proposition:

> > A set containing an element $a$, allows an Abelian group structure with
> >     identity element $a$.

?

By reference, I mean a formal reference to a paper or a book.

Comment: [cr](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208585/a-reference-for-every-set-containing-an-element-a-allows-a-abelian-group-str)

Comment: If you like you can refer to it as: "Herr mann, personal communication".

Comment: @Herrmann no I don't like.

Comment: Did you try this yet?: Hajnal, A.; Kertész, A. (1972). "Some new algebraic equivalents of the axiom of choice". Publ. Math. Debrecen 19: 339–340. (I found that in wikipedia)

Comment: You may also try to find that in http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=surv-59 (I haven't read the book and that paer yet)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Asaf Karagila at

[this stack exchange posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105433/does-every-set-have-a-group-structure?rq=1)

is rather thorough, and shows that the claim isn't necessarily true unless you believe the Axiom of Choice. I found it by looking at the list of "Related" questions to the right of your question. :)

Remark: I've now been downvoted for this answer. If this isn't a "reference" with a "proof," then I don't know what is. If OP meant "published in a printed-on-paper journal", perhaps OP should have said so.

Comment: I have the proof, but I need a reference to a paper or a book instead.

Comment: 1. You should have said so. 2. Is there someone that requires this? Perhaps you could provide the URL citation, and then include the body of Asaf's answer as an appendix if your editor/advisor/whatever doesn't want to allow it. I'll bet Asaf would be willing to give you the right to do so.

Comment: Yes. I forgot 'reference' has a more general meaning in English. I added this to the question.

Comment: and yes a journal editor has requested to add a reference for this. But it is a personal matter and mentioning this is not appropriate for the question.