# Confused about cyclic goups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

The cyclic group $\mathbb Z_6$ has a subgroup of order $3$ so I can deduce that $\mathbb Z_3$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_6$. On one hand, it seems false to me cause the group operations of the above groups are not the same. On the other hand, the subgroup of order $3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3$. I am confused...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot deduce that $\Bbb Z_3$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_6$. What you can deduce is that $\Bbb Z_6$ has a subgroup which is *isomorphic* to $\Bbb Z_3$.

Comment: I am going deep in elementary abstract algebra. I read this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105440/809841. it made me to ask myself the above question. Z6 has a subset of order 3 so this subset can be Z3. Am I right? Thx

Comment: When you wrote subset did you mean subgroup?

Comment: Sorry...Yes I meant subgroup. In fact, the cited link above is confusing me about the operations. If it is right (of course it is) then a set wit 6 elements can be considered as Z6 and every subset of order 5 of it can be considered as Z5 and a contradiction! I feel I am missing a prominent point. Thx

Comment: What that answer is saying is *not* that a set with $6$ elements can be considered $\Bbb Z_6$. It says that on any set with $6$ elements you can define a group structure on it that it will make it *isomorphic* to $\Bbb Z_6$.

Comment: Let me reflect...

Comment: Thx a lot for the time! and sorry for asking such this simple question...

Comment: Apparently, I can not put any comments on Arturo's neat answer so, may I ask something relevant to my question? It is between your answer above and his. Thx

Comment: Sure . The worst that can happen is that I suggest that you post that question as a new question.

Comment: I asked as you suggested

Comment: And I have provided an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ is not even a subset of $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$.

There are three members of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. Explicitly, they are:

\begin{align}
\{\ldots,{-7},{-4},{-1},2,5,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\\
\{\ldots,{-6},{-3},0,3,6,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\\
\{\ldots,{-5},{-2},1,4,7,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z
\end{align}

There are six members of $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$:

\begin{align}
\{\ldots,{-14},{-8},{-2},4,10,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z\\
\{\ldots,{-13},{-7},{-1},5,11,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z\\
\{\ldots,{-12},{-6},{0},6,12,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z\\
\{\ldots,{-11},{-5},{1},7,13,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z\\
\{\ldots,{-10},{-4},{2},8,14,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z\\
\{\ldots,{-9},{-3},{3},9,15,\ldots\}&\in\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z
\end{align}

Note that there is no $x$ such that $x\in\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ and $x\in\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$. The two sets have no members in common.

Since it isn't a subset, $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ either.

Comment: Thx for the time. I almost got what the defect was.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb{Z}_6$ has a subgroup $\{[0],[2],[4]\}$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_3$, but $\Bbb{Z}_3$ is not even a subset of $\Bbb{Z}_6$.