# Does my claim work for a set?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I don't have enough reputation to comment on [this neat answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105440/809841) so I ask here for some hints/answers. I take the set $A = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and so according to this answer, $A \sim \mathbb{Z}_4$. My question is: does that certain bijection allow to write the subset $\{0,2\}$ of $A$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $\{0,2\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

I asked this because I don't know the explicit rule of the bijection. Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily because how do you know the identity is contained in $\{0,2\}$?

Comment: Please include all the information needed in a  post.  Do not ask the reader to have to follow a link to understand what is being asked.

Comment: The answer in the question you link doesn't specify an explicit bijection. But if you take the most natural choice, that is, send $k$ to $k$ (mod 4), then yes $\{0,2\}$ is sent to a subgroup.

Comment: halrankard: thanks for the hint. I see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* $A\sim\Bbb Z_4$ means that $A$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$, then the statement doesn't make sense, since $A$ is simply a set, not a group. Given *any* bijection $b\colon A\longrightarrow\Bbb Z_4$, you can use it to define a group structure on $A$ by transport of structure: if $a_1,a_2\in A$, $a_1\oplus a_2=b^{-1}\bigl(b(a_1)+b(a_2)\bigr)$. Then $(A,\oplus)$ is a group which is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_4,+)$. And $\{0,2\}$ may be or may not be a subgroup  of $(A,\oplus)$; it depends upon the choice of $b$.

Comment: Thx. let me think.

Comment: You made the map a bit complicated for me, however; i got that. Can the most natrual choice work as commented? Thx

Comment: The most natural choice for *what*?

Comment: sending k to k (mod4), for example.

Comment: Then, yes, $\{0,2\}$ is a subgroup of $A$.

Comment: Thanks so much....I got your time today.